# How to return Dialog result ok from button click only if some condition are met

Tags: c#, winforms

I am tryin to create a costume messagebox with datavalidation(username , Password) in Visual studio winforms
I already made another one with the password only that will take the text box text encrypt it and compare it the the stored encrypted password

```
private void TextBoxPass_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    //Storedpassword is the stored password and ButtonOk is the confirm Button
    //Encrypt is the encription function
    if(Encrypt(TextBoxPass.Text)==StoredPassword)
        ButtonOk.DialogueResult=DialogueResult.OK;
}
```

this way i can easily capture the returned dialogue result.
but in the case where i have to verify Username And password from the database, I can't use the text change event cause it will connect to the database eachtime the User name or password text are changed so i tried the code below
This Part is the Dialogue result I call in the class passwordvalidation

```
public static DialogResult UserLogin()
    {
        using (FORMS.USER_LOGIN MSGPASS = new FORMS.USER_LOGIN())
        {
            DialogResult DLresult = MSGPASS.ShowDialog();
            return DLresult;
        }
    }
```

And this is the form USER_LOGIN form code

```
private DialogResult drslt(string USRNME,string Pss)
    {
        //Some code to Verify UserName and Password 
        //from database and return DataTable dt
        DialogResult DR;
        //COMPARE
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            //login successful
            DR = DialogResult.OK;  
        }
        else
        {
            //login unsuccussful
            DR = DialogResult.None;
        }
         return DR;
    }
private void BULCONFIRM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult DRS =drslt(TBULNAME.Text,TBULPassword.Text);
        if (DRS == DialogResult.OK)
            this.Close();
        else
            CLASS.CostumeMessages.ShowMessage("","",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
```

when I try to capture Dialogue result, it close the ShowDialogue form but it doesn't give the correct Dialogue result value

```
//Calling the DialogueResult
if(PasswordValidation.UserLogin()==DialogResult.OK)
            //do some stuff;
```

at the same time when I use the button Cancel which has the dialogueresult proprety =Cancel, the result works normally.
So what i want to know is if there is a mistake that i am making or if there is another way to return DialogueResult.OK when I click the CONFIRM button??

Comment: You need to set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` or `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel` as appropriate. You shouldn't need to call `this.Close()` after doing that, since the act of setting `this.DialogResult` should automatically close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:
In MainForm you open dialog form with this code (in a button click or where you want):

```
DialogForm form = new DialogForm();
 if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     // show menu
 }
```

and in Dialog form you on Login and in Cancel events you need to have similarity to this:

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if password is ok
            if(txtPassword.Text == "test")// check the password
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                // show error if password did not match
            }
        }

        private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
```